# A faster way to make a loop that takes as input previous iteration values

Tags: programming, code-review

As mention in other answers, I know that there are faster ways to construct loop in Mathematica, using `Fold` or `ListTable`. In my code, all the variables change in every iteration of the loop. Coming from an older school of programing languages, it is hard to convert my code into one more efficient. I would really appreciate some insight here, hoping that my case is representative of a common problem for new users in Mathematica. I paste here a representative self consistent piece of a much larger code.

My code propose a Boolean expression `a`. Then look for the truth table of this expression `b`, and the amount of variables in it `mdl`. Then look for the position of `b` in the array `concepts`, this is `pos`. Then check for the $current$ value in position `pos` in array `minimalong`, this is `min`. Finally, if `mdl` is smaller than `min`, aggregate the expression `a` to `winnerx` in position `pos` and update `minimalong`.

```
concepts = Tuples[{0, 1}, 16];
minimalong = ConstantArray[1000, Length[concepts]];
winnerx = ConstantArray[0, Length[concepts]];
letters = List["p", "q", "y", "s", "!p", "!q", "!y", "!s"];
combx1 = Subsets[letters, {2}]

For[i=1,i<(Length[combx1]+1),i++,
a=And[Part[Part[combx1,i],1],Part[Part[combx1,i],2]];
b=Boole[BooleanTable[a,{p,q,y,s}]];
mdl=  1 * (StringCount[ToString[a],{"p","q","y","s"}] );
pos=Sum[Part[b,h]*(2^(16-h)),{h,16}]+1;
min=Part[minimalong,pos];
If[mdl<min,Part[minimalong,pos]=mdl;Part[winnerx,pos]= a];
];
```

**EDIT**

I tried this, but it is in fact taking MORE time that the for loop..

```
ands[wo_, i_] := (Module[{a, b, min, mdl, pos}, 
a = And[Part[Part[combx1, i], 1], Part[Part[combx1, i], 2]];
b = Boole[BooleanTable[a, {p, q, y, s}]];
pos = Sum[Part[b, h]*(2^(16 - h)), {h, 16}] + 1;
min = Part[minimalong, pos];
mdl  = var * (StringCount[ToString[a], {"p", "q", "y", "s"}] );
If[mdl < min, Part[winnerx, pos] = a];
If[mdl < min, Part[minimalong, pos] = mdl];
winnerx]);

lon = ConstantArray[0, Length[concepts]];
Fold[ands, lon, Range[Length[combx1]]];
```

Any Help?

Comment: Could you explain what do exactly your code

Comment: I edited the question :)

Comment: What is `var` ?

Comment: Sorry, var is 1